# Доработка программы поиска и замены слов. Python

Tags: python

Есть программа. Она берет текст из буфера обмена, находит в нем некоторые слова или части слов (повторяющиеся слова программа пропускает), возвращает в буфер обмена измененные слова. К примеру:

В буфере обмена есть некоторый текст: "1, B1, 34e1 mevb a1b1cd, c1bn d1ek".

Программа ищет части слов: 'A1','B1','C1','D1','E1','F1','G1','H1','I1','J1','K1','L1','M1','N1'.

Программа вернет в буфер обмена: "A2, B2, C2, D2, E2" (Программа не чувствительна к регистру)

Но появилась проблема - нужно, чтобы программа выводила слова именно в том порядке в котором они были указаны в тексте. То есть теперь, если текст останется тот же, программа должна вывести не "A2, B2, C2, D2, E2", а "B2, E2, A2, C2, D2".

Вот сама программа:

```
import pyperclip
import re
while 1==1:
    begining = input('copy the text')
    text = pyperclip.paste()
    print(text)
    words = ['A1','B1','C1','D1','E1','F1','G1','H1','I1','J1','K1','L1','M1','N1']
    variants = ['A2','B2','C2','D2','E2','F2','G2','H2','I2','J2','K2','L2','M2','N2']
    result = []
    n = 0
    while n < len(words) :
        word = str(words[n])
        resultofsearch = re.search(word, text)
        if resultofsearch != None:
            resultofsearch = resultofsearch.group(0)
            resultofsearch = resultofsearch.lower()
        word = word.lower()
        resultofsearch2 = re.search(word, text)
        if resultofsearch2 != None:
            resultofsearch2 = resultofsearch2.group(0)
        if resultofsearch == word:
            result.append(variants[n])
        elif resultofsearch2 == word:
            result.append(variants[n])
        else:
            pass
        n += 1
    endresult = ', '.join(result)
    print(', '.join(result))
    pyperclip.copy(endresult)
    exit = input('Press + if you want to exit')
    if exit == str('+'):
        break
```

Comment: «проблема - нужно, чтобы» — это не проблема, это задача.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
words = ['A1','B1','C1','D1','E1','F1','G1','H1','I1','J1','K1','L1','M1','N1']  # upper()
variants = ['A2','B2','C2','D2','E2','F2','G2','H2','I2','J2','K2','L2','M2','N2']

def index_variant(text):
    TEXT = text.upper()  # не чувствительна к регистру
    for (word, variant) in zip(words, variants):
        index = TEXT.find(word)  # в том порядке в котором они были указаны в тексте
        if index != -1:
            yield index, variant

text = "1, B1, 34e1 mevb a1b1cd, c1bn d1ek"
result = ', '.join(variant for (index, variant) in sorted(index_variant(text)))
print(result)  # "B2, E2, A2, C2, D2"
```